# Parsing hierarchical information from XML to sqlite

Tags: python, xml, sqlite

The scripts that I post will be long so I beg your patience. I believe it is easy to solve for people who are familiar with the complexity of XML structure. I have a highly hierarchical XML file. I would love to make sqlite database based on it. The two files I have so far extract sibling information from a XML file with this structure (note - the frequency of work varies from 0 to 4 or 5; nodes can also be empty):

```
<program>
    <id>28798031</id>
    <programID>12345</programID>
    <orchestra>New York Philarmonic</orchestra>
    <season>1842-43</season>
    <concertInfo>
        <eventType>Subscription Season</eventType>
        <Location>Manhattan, NY</Location>
        <Venue>Apollo Rooms</Venue>
        <Date>1842-12-07T05:00:00Z</Date>
        <Time>8:00PM</Time>
    </concertInfo>
    <worksInfo>
        <work ID="52446*">
            <composerName>Beethoven,  Ludwig  van</composerName>
            <workTitle>SYMPHONY NO. 5 IN C MINOR, OP.67</workTitle>
            <conductorName>Hill, Ureli Corelli</conductorName>
        </work>
        <work ID="8834*4">
            <composerName>Weber,  Carl  Maria Von</composerName>
            <workTitle>OBERON</workTitle>
            <movement>"Ozean, du Ungeheuer" (Ocean, thou mighty monster), Reiza (Scene and Aria), Act II</movement>
            <conductorName>Timm, Henry C.</conductorName>
            <soloists>
                <soloist>
                    <soloistName>Otto, Antoinette</soloistName>
                    <soloistInstrument>Soprano</soloistInstrument>
                    <soloistRoles>S</soloistRoles>
                </soloist>
            </soloists>
        </work>
    </worksInfo>
</program>
```

I have the two scripts that extract data from sibling nodes (the same hierarchical level).

**First**

```
import sqlite3
import xml.etree.cElementTree

def insert_program(db_conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo):
curs = db_conn.cursor()
curs.execute("insert into program values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo))
db_conn.commit()

def program_data_from_element(element):
id = element.find("id").text
programID = element.find("programID").text
orchestra = element.find("orchestra").text
season = element.find("season").text
concertInfo = element.find("concertInfo").text
worksInfo = element.find("worksInfo").text
return id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo

## add the main loop to get all the programs from the XML file
if __name__ == "__main__":
conn = sqlite3.connect("program.sqlite3")
program = xml.etree.cElementTree.parse("complete.xml")
program = program.findall("program")
for index, element in enumerate(program):
    id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo  = program_data_from_element(element)
    insert_program(conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo)
```

**Second**

```
import sqlite3
import xml.etree.cElementTree

def insert_work(db_conn, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName):
curs = db_conn.cursor()
curs.execute("insert into work values (?,?,?,?,?)", (workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName))
db_conn.commit()

def work_data_from_element(element):
workID = element.get("ID")
if workID != None:
    workID = workID
else:
    workID = ''
composerName = element.find("composerName")
if composerName != None:
    composerName = composerName.text
else:
    composerName = ''
workTitle = element.find("workTitle")
if workTitle != None:
    workTitle = workTitle.text
else:
    workTitle = ''
movement = element.find("movement")
if movement != None:
    movement = movement.text
else:
    movement = ''
conductorName = element.find("conductorName")
if conductorName != None:
    conductorName = conductorName.text
else:
    conductorName = ''
return workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName


## add the main loop to get all the work information from the XML file
if __name__ == "__main__":
conn = sqlite3.connect("work.sqlite3")
programs = xml.etree.cElementTree.parse("complete.xml")
work = programs.findall("program/worksInfo/work")
for index, element in enumerate(work):
    workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName = work_data_from_element(element)
    insert_work(conn, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName)
```

My issue is -- how to connect the two together so I can know the programID, season, workID and conductorName, etc., all together? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever working with nested, hierarchical XML files that need to be flattened for two-dimensional formats like database tables, consider an XSLT solution. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special-purpose programming language designed to transform XML files and like most general purpose languages, Python can process XSLT 1.0 scripts, specifically using the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module.

So for both *program* and *work* SQLite tables, consider running the following XSLT scripts to transform the source XML file and then parse with XPath (sibling to XSLT) for database import all in one Python script. By the way, XSLT is a well-formed XML file so can be loaded from file or string like any other XML. The beauty too of XSLT is you can hard-code elements that may/may not exist so returns empty text for missing nodes.

A few changes to your structure:

1. Concatenated all children of `<concerntInfo>` (maybe use as separate table?)
2. Removed `<worksInfo>` from *program* parsing since it reflects in *work* table
3. Added the corresponding program `<id>` to *work* parsing to use as foreign key in table

---

**Program XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to be called in Python)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <program>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="program"/>
    </program>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="program">
    <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
    <programID><xsl:value-of select="programID"/></programID>
    <orchestra><xsl:value-of select="orchestra"/></orchestra>
    <season><xsl:value-of select="season"/></season>
    <concertInfo><xsl:value-of select="concat(concertInfo/eventType, ' ',
                   concertInfo/Location, ' ', concertInfo/Venue, ' ', 
                   concertInfo/Date, ' ', concertInfo/Time)"/></concertInfo>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Work XSLT** *(save as .xsl to be called in Python)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="program">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="worksInfo"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="worksInfo">    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="work"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="work">
    <xsl:copy>
      <programID><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::program/id"/></programID>
      <workID><xsl:value-of select="@workID"/></workID>
      <composerName><xsl:value-of select="composerName"/></composerName>
      <workTitle><xsl:value-of select="workTitle"/></workTitle>
      <movement><xsl:value-of select="movement"/></movement>
      <conductorName><xsl:value-of select="conductorName"/></conductorName>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python Script**

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import sqlite3

def insert_program(db_conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo):
    curs = db_conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("insert into program values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo))
    db_conn.commit()

def program_data_from_element(element):
    id = element.find("id").text
    programID = element.find("programID").text
    orchestra = element.find("orchestra").text
    season = element.find("season").text
    concertInfo = element.find("concertInfo").text

    return id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo

def insert_work(db_conn, programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName):
    curs = db_conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("insert into work values (?,?,?,?,?)", (programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName))
    db_conn.commit()

def work_data_from_element(element):
    programID = element.find("programID").text
    workID = element.find("workID").text
    composerName = element.find("composerName").text
    workTitle = element.find("workTitle").text
    movement = element.find("movement").text
    conductorName = element.find("conductorName").text

    return programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, conductorName, movement    

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    conn = sqlite3.connect("program.sqlite3")
    xml = ET.parse("complete.xml")

    # PROGRAM PARSE
    xslt = ET.parse("program.xsl")
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(xml)
    program = newdom.xpath("//program")    

    for index, element in enumerate(program):
        id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo = program_data_from_element(element)
        insert_program(conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo)

    # WORK PARSE
    xslt = ET.parse("work.xsl")
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(xml)
    work = newdom.xpath("//work")    

    for index, element in enumerate(work):
        programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, conductorName, movement = work_data_from_element(element)
        insert_work(conn, programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, conductorName, movement)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the scripts. I tried them on my laptop but could not get through a few things. One of them seems to be related to 'worksInfo'. I tried to insert it in the loop or deleted it from the table definition. I also tried to insert it in the .xsl file. None of them works. Do you know what would the problem be? Thank you!!

Comment: What is the exact error? At one line? As mentioned, I removed *worksInfo* from the *program* section since it would repeat the data in work table. So this answer may not work with your exact version. Try the version I posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the scripts and answering my questions. I had the problem in insert_program(). It is 'File "first.py", line 45, in <module>
    insert_program(conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo)
TypeError: insert_program() takes exactly 7 arguments (6 given)', so I shifted around lines and now each has worksInfo in it. It seems fine now.

Comment: What I have changed - 'def insert_program(db_conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo):
    curs = db_conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("insert into program values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo))
    db_conn.commit()'

Comment: In def program_data_from_element(element) '    worksInfo = element.find("worksInfo")

    return str(id), str(programID), str(orchestra), str(season), str(concertInfo), str(worksInfo)' (I also deleted .text and added str() because .text did not work but this is irrelevant)

Comment: In the loop, I have this '    for index, element in enumerate(program):
        id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo = program_data_from_element(element)
        insert_program(conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo, worksInfo)'

Comment: But now I am having this error that I am trying to fix 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 56, in <module>
    insert_work(conn, programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName)
  File "first.py", line 21, in insert_work
    curs.execute("insert into work values (?,?,?,?,?)", (programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table work has 1 columns but 5 values were supplied'

Comment: I changed the script in #WORK PARSE '    for index, element in enumerate(work):
        programID = program_data_from_element(element)
        workID, composerName, workTitle, conductorName, movement = work_data_from_element(element)
        insert_work(conn, programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName)', it shows '  File "first.py", line 56, in <module>
    workID, composerName, workTitleValueError: too many values to unpack'

Comment: In def insert_work, I also added one more question mark (?) to accommodate programID, and I received '  File "first.py", line 56, in <module>
    workID, composerName, workTitle, conductorName, movement = work_data_from_element(element)
ValueError: too many values to unpack'

Comment: I deleted programID from def program_data_from_element(element), and received this error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 56, in <module>
    insert_work(conn, programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName)
  File "first.py", line 21, in insert_work
    curs.execute("insert into work values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (programID, workID, composerName, workTitle, movement, conductorName))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table work has 1 columns but 6 values were supplied', and I guess I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: Apologies, I just found my mistake. I did not remove *worksInfo* in parameter program function and did not add *programID* parameter in work function which resulted in unmatched values. Please test with posted XML and this updated py script. Also, the other error seems to say the work DB table has only one column.

Comment: Ah, I am pretty confused. I am not sure why I cannot find the program table. Here is the error ` File "second.py", line 45, in <module>
    insert_program(conn, id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo)
  File "second.py", line 6, in insert_program
    curs.execute("insert into program values (?,?,?,?,?)", (id, programID, orchestra, season, concertInfo))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: program`